# how to replace img url in a array

Tags: php, html, curl

i am getting data from a ulr so now want to change url of image, my code is

```
@$domain = $_REQUEST['domain'];
function get_dns($url, $curl = true) {
    $responseString = '';
    if (!$curl) {
        $responseString = file_get_contents($url);
    } else {
        $ch = curl_init( $url );
        $options = array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Type: text/html', 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36') , 

        );
        curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
        $responseString =  curl_exec($ch);
    }
    return $responseString;
}

$url ="http://intodns.scriptburn.com/index.php?domain=$domain";
$query = get_dns($url);
preg_match_all('/<!-- BEGIN CONTENT -->(.*?)<!-- END CONTENT -->/s', $query, $content);
echo $content = $content[0][0];
```

here i am want to replace `<img src="static/images/` to `<img src="https://www.whoisextractor.in/wp-content/themes/whois/img/`

Comment: if you want to replace a well known string with another, why not use `str_replace`?

Comment: you should also consider using an HTML parser instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got Solution my self with the help of https://stackoverflow.com/a/14575485/2384642

Now my code is

```
    $url ="http://intodns.scriptburn.com/index.php?domain=$domain";
    $query = get_dns($url);
    preg_match_all('/<!-- BEGIN CONTENT -->(.*?)<!-- END CONTENT -->/s', $query, $content);
    $content = $content[0][0];
    $content = preg_replace_callback('~<img\ssrc="static/images/~i', 
    function($m)
    {
        return sprintf('<img src="https://www.whoisextractor.in/wp-content/themes/whois/img/', urlencode($m[1]), $m[2], $m[3]);
    }, $content);
    echo $content;
```